# MonoDevelop / XCode Build successful. Build failed. Invalid data

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xcode4.5

I just updated Xcode for use with iOS 6, and for some reason, when I build and try to deploy in the Debug iPhone mode, I'm getting:

```
Build successful.
Build failed. Invalid data
```

If I take out my Bundle Identifier in the iPhone Application / iOS Target, it gives me this error:

Build successful.
Project does not have bundle identifier specified. Generated 'com.company.app' to match provisioning profile.
Build failed. Invalid data

I'm using Xcode 4.5 and MonoDevelop 3.0.3.4 and MonoTouch 5.3.4.

I don't have any spaces in the bundle identifier or underscores.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

MonoTouch 5.3.x and MonoDevelop 3.0.3.x are a bit too *old* for Xcode 4.5.

Xcode 4.5 changed the format of some of it's `Info.plist` files from XML to binary and the tooling required some updates to work with them.

MonoTouch 5.4 (and 6.0) and MonoDevelop 3.0.4.x **will work** with Xcode 4.5.